# Run-Time Check Failure #2, Arrays and confusion

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a problem with my code, it inputs 92 temperatures in from a file into 3 arrays, If I comment out the third array the issue of "Corruption" on one of the other arrays goes away, however anytime I add the third arrays parameters in, the program has the error "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'Apr' was corrupted." I have tried using different loops or putting each array in its own function I have no clue what to do! could use some help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void readData(double March[], double April[], double May[]) {

    ifstream inputFile;

    inputFile.open("pgm6.txt");
    
        for(int i = 0; i < 93; i++){

            if (i < 31) {
                inputFile >> March[i];
                cout << "March " << March[i] << endl;
            }
            if (i > 30 && i < 61) {
                inputFile >> April[i];
                cout << "April " << April[i] << endl;
            }
            if (i > 60 && i < 92) {
                inputFile >> May[i];
                cout << "May " << May[i] << endl;
            }
            if (i > 91) {
                break;
            }
        }


}

int main() {

    
    double Mar[31], Apr[30], My[31];

    readData(Mar, Apr, My);

    
    return 0;
```

Comment: `April[i]` exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing an index out of bounds. Seeing as `i > 30`

Comment: Make a separate loop for each month. Start the loop index at 0 for all 3.

Comment: How do I read from the 92 lines of the file then?

Comment: You read 31 lines for March. 30 for April then 31 for May.

Answer (score 2):

In C or C++, arrays are indexed starting from zero, so in your loop, access to the `April` and `May` arrays will be out of bounds.

In C++, it is recommended to use `std::vector` or `std::array` instead of the C array.

```
template <class MarchT, class AprilT, class MayT>
void readData(MarchT &March, AprilT &April, MayT &May)
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("pgm6.txt");

    for (auto &Value : March) {
        inputFile >> Value;
        cout << "March " << Value << endl;
    }

    for (auto &Value : April) {
        inputFile >> Value;
        cout << "April " << Value << endl;
    }

    for (auto &Value : May) {
        inputFile >> Value;
        cout << "May " << Value << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::array<double, 31> Mar;
    std::array<double, 30> Apr;
    std::array<double, 31> My;

    readData(Mar, Apr, My);

    return 0;
}
```

If you don't understand the C++ template yet, you can just:

```
void readData(
    std::array<double, 31> &March,
    std::array<double, 30> &April,
    std::array<double, 31> &May
)
{
    /* Same as above */
}
```